# Disable import of classes for PHPDoc

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

One thing I love about PhpStorm is the easy import of classes (adding the use statement for you).  However, the annoyance with this is when you don't actually want it to import the class.  For example, when I'm documenting a method's return value as another class.

Is there any way to disable PhpStorm's import of classes only when annotating in PHPDoc blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly...

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `PHPDoc` tab
4. There is `Use fully-qualified class names` under `Generated Doc Blocks`

That option does the job when completing **not-yet-imported class** in `@return` (should do the same for `@param` and others -- have not tested other tags myself -- only checked on `@return`).

[image]

---

**On related note:** this ticket is asking to have an ability to always use FQN in PHPDoc blocks (implemented as Inspection .. so can be turned on or off). Might be useful for you -- consider voting.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28591

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.