# How to correctly document aliased object types?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpdoc

If I have imported a class under an alias:

```
use My\Other\ClassName as OtherClass;
```

How should I document types of that class? Do I use the alias or not?

**a)** `@return \My\Other\ClassName`

**b)** `@return OtherClass`

**c)** Another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPDoc supports fully qualified classes, relative classes, aliases, and references to self (static, $this)

http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html

The most common practice I've seen is using fully qualified class names (e.g. \My\Other\ClassName) which in my opinion, is the best way to document external classes since the person reading the doc block doesn't have to look in a different place to see what OtherClass refers to.

If using phpstorm, take a look at a question I asked recently: [Disable import of classes for PHPDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497042/disable-import-of-classes-for-phpdoc)

Comment: I agree it makes more sense to use the fully qualified name for clarity. Thanks.